# mysql: delete rows between repeating specific values

Tags: mysql

SQL rookie here.  I have a broken punch in/out type table with millions of records fed by a legacy bad app that did not check for previous logins/logouts before merrily inserting another duplicate record.  The app is fixed but I need to sanitize the table to retain the historical data so it can be fed into future reports.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to keep each minimum login row followed by the next minimum logout row and discard everything else between.  The bad app allowed both duplicate logins AND logouts... grrrr.

Every "duplicate row" type question I've searched for here doesn't seem to apply to this type of grouping situation.  From being a long time SO lurker I know you guys would like to see what I've already tried but have already tried tens of goofy query attempts that aren't coming close. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the table and what I'm trying to do [and the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/149802/1) with schema

```
+---------------------+-------+-------------+---------------+
| calldate            | agent | etype       | uniqueid      |
+---------------------+-------+-------------+---------------+
| 2018-02-02 19:26:47 | 501   | agentlogin  | 1517599607.71 |
| 2018-02-02 19:26:55 | 501   | agentlogin  | 1517599615.72 |<-- delete
| 2018-02-02 19:27:32 | 501   | agentlogoff | 1517599652.73 |
| 2018-02-02 19:27:43 | 501   | agentlogin  | 1517599663.74 |
| 2018-02-02 19:28:24 | 501   | agentlogoff | 1517599704.75 |
| 2018-02-02 19:29:02 | 501   | agentlogoff | 1517599742.76 |<-- delete
| 2018-02-02 19:29:39 | 501   | agentlogoff | 1517599778.77 |<-- delete
| 2018-02-02 19:34:54 | 501   | agentlogin  | 1517600094.80 |
| 2018-02-02 19:35:23 | 501   | agentlogin  | 1517600122.81 |<-- delete
| 2018-02-02 19:35:49 | 501   | agentlogin  | 1517600149.82 |<-- delete
| 2018-02-02 19:36:04 | 501   | agentlogoff | 1517600164.83 |
| 2018-02-02 19:36:08 | 501   | agentlogoff | 1517600168.84 |<-- delete
+---------------------+-------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: How big is the table? Is there a primary key?

Comment: This isn't wildly different from your last, is it?

Comment: @Paul Spiegel - The production table has millions of rows and other unrelated data and columns.  For clarity I only dumped the pertinent rows/columns into my fiddle test table and didn't dump the primary key id column.  The uniqueid column is 100% unique, however.

Comment: @Strawberry - No it is not, however, I wanted to ask a new question because the original question was related to sum/diff the elapsed seconds and as walter pointed out the best way to handle this situation is fix the table.  I tried many variations of his example and they did not work due to the problems of the duplicate records on both sides of the logins/logouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a copy of the table with an auto_increment column. This way you can compare two neighbor rows more easily and more efficiently.

Find in the new table the rows which have the same `agent` and `etype` as in the previous row and join the result with the original table using the unique column in a DELETE statement.

```
create table tmp (
    `id` int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    `calldate` datetime,
    `uniqueid` varchar(32),
    `agent` varchar(80),
    `etype` varchar(80)
) as
  select null as id, calldate, uniqueid, agent, etype
  from test
  order by agent, calldate, uniqueid
;

delete t
from tmp t1
join tmp t2
  on  t2.id = t1.id + 1
  and t2.agent = t1.agent
  and t2.etype = t1.etype
join test t on t.uniqueid = t2.uniqueid;

drop table tmp;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e96b/2

You should however first have an index on `uniqueid`.

Comment: I originally marked Obie's answer as correct but technically yours is the correct answer because Obie's solution pulls out the "good" rows while yours identifies the rows to delete.  I'm grateful for the help.  Thank you for figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
select calldate,agent,etype,uniqueid 
from test as t1 
where not exists
(select *
 from 
 test as t2
 where t2.agent=t1.agent
 and t2.etype=t1.etype
 and t2.uniqueid<t1.uniqueid
 and t2.uniqueid>ifnull((select max(uniqueid )
              from test t3
              where t3.agent=t1.agent
              and t3.etype<>t1.etype
              and t3.uniqueid<t1.uniqueid),0)
 )
order by uniqueid;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/149802/16

Comment: that works perfectly.  THANK YOU.  I cannot believe how quick you came up with that answer.  Maybe someday I can wrap my head around SQL but I'm just a lowly jack of trades.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help!  Your JSFiddle was helpful!